# Laravel 4: Reference controller object inside filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller in Laravel 4, with a custom variable declared within it.

```
class SampleController extends BaseController{
      public $customVariable;
}
```

Two questions: Is there any way I can call within a route filter:

1. The controller object where the filter is running at.
2. The custom variable from that specific controller ($customVariable).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per this post: 
http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=47380#p47380

You can only pass parameters to filters as strings.

```
//routes.php
Route::get('/', ['before' => 'auth.level:1', function()
{
return View::make('hello');
}]);
```

and

```
//filters.php
Route::filter('auth.level', function($level)
{
   //$level is 1
});
```

In controllers, it would look more like this

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->filter('before', 'someFilter:param1,param2');
}
```

**EDIT:**

Should this not suffice to your needs, you can allways define the filter inside the controller's constructor. If you need access to the current controller ($this) and it's custom fields and you have many different classes you want to have that in, you can put the filter in BaseController's constructor and extend it in all classes you need.

```
class SomeFancyController extends BaseController {

protected $customVariable

/**
 * Instantiate a new SomeFancyController instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $ctrl = $this;
    $this->beforeFilter(function() use ($ctrl)
    {
        //
        // do something with $ctrl
        // do something with $ctrl->customVariable;
    });
}
```

}

**EDIT 2 :**

As per your new question I realised the above example had a small error - as I forgot the closure has local scope. So it's correct now I guess.

Comment: Hi Gadoma and thanks for helping out but I don't think this is an answer. I know I can pass variables into filters, but I'm looking in to calling the controller within the filter is running at and also that custom variable. I would appreciate any help regarding that. Thanks!

Comment: You can always specify the filter inside the Controller's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare it as static in your controller, you can call it statically from outside the controller

Controller:

```
class SampleController extends BaseController
{
    public static $customVariable = 'test';
}
```

Outside your controller

`echo SampleController::$customVariable`

Comment: The variable is not static so there should a controller instance. Got the answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->beforeFilter('auth', ['controller' => $this]);
}
```