# Laravel 4: How can I call the controller inside a filter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this class and filter:

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->afterFilter(function()
    {
        if ($this->response_type == 'json'){

        }
    });
}
```

When this line runs...

```
if ($this->response_type == 'json'){
```

...I'm referring the controller, but somehow it's calling filter so I can't do anything with the parent object.

Is there any way I can just call the controller class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a closure (anonymous function) you can specify what "external" variables you want to use as otherwise the scope of the closure is local.

my guess, this should work for you

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $ctrl = $this;
    $this->afterFilter(function() use ($ctrl)
    {
        if ($ctrl->response_type == 'json')
        {
        //do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for the confusion - after all, this post is duplicate to [Laravel 4: Reference controller object inside filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093861/laravel-4-reference-controller-object-inside-filter/18102596#18102596)